# impdp in Oracle. Why it does not create users?

Tags: oracle, database-migration, datapump, impdp

I am newbie in oracle and I am facing troubles with `impdp`. I have a production server and I have created a new server for testing purposes, so I installed centos, oracle and created the database `"sire"`. Now I make a dump from the production server with the following command:

```
expdp system/password@sire full=Y 
directory=pump_dir dumpfile=sire_dump.dmp logfile=sire.log
```

The I come to the new server, and I execute impdp:

```
    impdp system/password@sire full=Y 
directory=pump_directorio dumpfile=sire_dump.dmp logfile=sire_imp.log
```

It starts to do the import but then I receive errors such as:

> "the user vberrios does not exist". And also error beause it cannot
>   found some schemas and tablespaces.

My question is: It is not supposed that `impdp full=Y` must import all users and schemas? I have read that I have to create the users in the destination server but I have about 300 users in the database. How can I do a full import in a empty server. I just want to import the full database and user and all objects.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/dp_import.htm), that impdp will create uses, when the dump file contains the create user statements:

> If the schema you are remapping to does not already exist, the import
>   operation creates it, provided the dump file set contains the
>   necessary CREATE USER metadata and you are importing with enough
>   privileges.

So either your dump file is incomplete (for example due to missing privileges) or you are lacking privileges on the target database.

So please check your privileges on both, the source database and the target database. Please update your question with then according information. For the export to include the schema definitions, you must have the `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE` privilege.

Comment: OP said that he user `system` user. What bigger permission is required than `system` user has already?

Comment: Had the same issue with `system` user. Adding `DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE` privilege actually helped. I don't think that `system` user has full exp/imp privileges by default.