# Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c migration on solaris 10

Tags: database, oracle10g, oracle12c, solaris-10, database-dump

I have been assigned to move 10g database to Oracle 12c on a Solaris. Size of data is around 68 GB.

So far I have managed to install the Oracle 12c on Solaris and also created the default DB it asks for. Now I'm trying to import the dump into Oracle 12c db which is proving to be problematic to me. I didn't take the dump, it was provided to me and told me that it was taken of the entire DB with exp utility.

I'm trying to import it using this:

```
  imp file=/bkofa/dump/backup_dmp.dmp full=y;
```

and then

when it asks me for Username I provide this:

```
  / as sysdba
```

but it never imports anything and always gives me with errors like Users this and this doesn't exist and so on>

So I tried to create Users manually like this:

```
CREATE USER c##AFXAML
IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'B010B6069516DE73'
DEFAULT TABLESPACE AFXUSER
PROFILE DEFAULT
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

I also tried with simply providing name like AFXAML without appending c## but still gives me an error that invalid username.

Please help me how to resolve this by either pointing me to a guide that shows how to setup a 12c db from the get go for import and please tell me why the full option doesn't work and it asks to create all the users separately. Currently there's something like 30 users and 4 tablespaces.

Comment: The old exp/imp expect users (and tablespaces) to already exist, as you've discovered. Is there a reason you aren't using datapump, [which can create isers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30702548/266304)? Regarding your manual user creation attempt, are you trying/planning to import into the root container, or a PDB?

Comment: Can you please clarify between root container or PDB?

Comment: It's explained [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89250). See the previous chapter too.

Comment: No, I'm importing in the root container and secondly the guy responsible for providing the dump told me that expdp was not working for sys user.